# Problem in installing COCOAPI for TensorFlow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, visual-c++, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am following [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) guide to setup my virtual environment for TensorFlow object detection API. According to this API, I need to install COCOAPI, but I am failed to do so.

I installed MS visual c++ 2015 but still error was occurring when I ran this command
`pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI`

**The error**

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
  Cloning https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git to c:\users\talha\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-mrsjlt3h
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git 'C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-mrsjlt3h'
  Resolved https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git to commit 2929bd2ef6b451054755dfd7ceb09278f935f7ad
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  Building wheel for pycocotools (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
  Running setup.py clean for pycocotools
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-mrsjlt3h\PythonAPI\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
          cythonize(ext_modules)
        File "C:\Users\talha\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 973, in cythonize
          module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
        File "C:\Users\talha\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 816, in create_extension_list
          for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
        File "C:\Users\talha\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 114, in nonempty
          raise ValueError(error_msg)
      ValueError: 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx' doesn't match any files
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for pycocotools
Failed to build pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The same error occurred even after installing MS Visual C++ 14.0. Could you please suggest some solutions?